# Conditional argparse with choice option

Tags: python, conditional-statements, argparse

Below are three arguments I am writing in a module.

```py
parser.add_argument('--Type',type=str,choices=['a','b','c'],help='Options include: a,b,c.',required=True)

parser.add_argument('--Input',default=False,help='Generate input files',required=False)

parser.add_argument('--Directory',default=False,help='Secondary directory',required='--Input' in sys.argv)
```

The `--Type` is possible with three options: a,b,c.

Currently, I have it set up so that, if --Directory is true, it requires --Input to be true.

However, I would like add an additional condition to --Directory to require --Type to be == 'c'.

How do I alter the required option in the --Directory argument so that it needs both --Input and --Type == 'c'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decouple argument parsing from your requirements.

```
parser.add_argument('--Type', choices=['a','b','c'], required=True)
parser.add_argument('--Input', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--Directory', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.Directory and args.Type != 'c' and not args.input:
    raise argparse.ArgumentError("--Directory requires --Type c and --Input")
```

(Note that `action='store_true'` automatically sets `type=bool` and `default=False`.)

Comment: Isn't it idiomatic to have options in small letters?

Comment: Depends on whose idiom you are attempting to follow. I'm not *aware* of any that use capitalized option names, but that doesn't mean they don't exist. That said, yes, GNU-style long options usually do not start with uppercase letters.

Comment: 'a','b','c' are just placeholders for this question. I kept some of this information hidden.  I was unaware of the action='store_true'. This is helpful!

Comment: @AndrewHamel I think gmds was referring to your choice of `--Type` vs a more common name like `--type`.

Comment: I see. Does this solution also work if I have other parser.add_arguments.  For example, I don't see the user always needing to use the --Directory flag

Comment: A solution *like* this will. It's just a matter of clearly deciding what the logic needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the `required` parameter for either of those things, it is kind of error-prone and not very readable. Just check the validity of the arguments after parsing.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--Type', type=str, choices=['a','b','c'], help='Options include: a,b,c.', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--Input', default=False, help='Generate input files', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--Directory', default=False, help='Secondary directory', required=False)
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    if parsed_args.Directory and not (parsed_args.Input and parsed_args.Type == 'c'):
        parser.error('option --Directory requires --Input and --Type c.')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest, but you could look up the argument next to `--Type` and check that that is equal to `'c'` like so:

```
parser.add_argument('--Directory', default=False, help='secondary directory',
                    required=('--Type' in sys.argv and
                              sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--Type') + 1] == 'c')
                   )
```

Comment: Thank you, I considered adding a conditional statement outside of the argparser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is also possible to do something like this

```
import sys

# Your past code here

args = parser.parse_args()

type = args.Type
input = args.Input
directory = args.Directory

if directory:
    if input != 'c':
        print 'error in argument'
        sys.exit(1)
```