# how to make an argument required based on another argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Given a small parser:

```
from argparse import ArgumentError, ArgumentParser
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('x', choices=['1', '2'])
p.add_argument('--y', required=False)
p.parse_args('1 --y 2'.split()) # this would work
p.parse_args('1'.split()) # this would work also
```

However, I want to ensure that if `x=='1'`, then `--y` would get a value. My implementation was this:

```
args = p.parse_args('1 --y 2'.split())
if args.x=='1' and not args.y:
     raise ArgumentError('blah')
```

Is there an inner argparse way to do this? it looks much better when argparse throws a parsing error

*Even better, I want the `--y` arg will be required when `x=='1'` and not allowed when `x=='2'`*

Comment: Your problem could be cast as subparsers.  That's the only builtin mechanism for making one set of arguments depend on the value of another.  Otherwise post-parsing testing is the easiest approach.  The parser doesn't have to do everything!

Comment: See related/possible duplicate: [Conditional argparse with choice option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55595539/1782792). You can use the `error` method of the parser to trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

## *‘I want to ensure that if `x` == '1', then `--y` would get a value’*

You could use this:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from sys import argv

p = ArgumentParser(prog='MyParser')

yIsRequired = (argv[1] == '1') # True if x == '1' else False

p.add_argument('x')            # Positional argument
p.add_argument(
    '--y',                     # Optional argument
    required=yIsRequired,
)

p = p.parse_args()
```

It's all tested. This code:

- Checks `sys.argv` for `x`.
- **If `x` == `'1'` then `yIsRequired` is set to `True`
- `y`'s `required` parameter is set to the value of `yIsRequired`

## *‘Even better, I want the --y arg will be required when x=='1' and not allowed when x=='2'’*

Here you go:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys

p = ArgumentParser(prog='Demo')

yIsRequired = (sys.argv[1] == '1')

p.add_argument('x')
p.add_argument(
    '--y',
    required=yIsRequired,
)

if sys.argv[1] == '2' and '--y' in sys.argv:                    # If x == 2 and y has a value
    sys.stderr.write('Demo: error: argument --y not allowed\n') # Write error to standard error output
    sys.exit(1)                                                 # Exit with non-zero exit code

p = p.parse_args()
```

### Conclusion:

- `sys.argv` contains all arguments passed to your script (it is a `list`)
- You can use `sys.argv` to check whether arguments have been passed (boolean logic)
- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807319/disable-remove-argument-in-argparse#32807403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807319/disable-remove-argument-in-argparse) for help on removing/disabling arguments. There are quite a few answers, but many are worth reading.

Comment: Mixing argv is not ideal. I prefer a way that uses only argparse methods. Using the way i posted and replacing the raise with argparse.error would give much nicer results

Comment: @CIsForCookies It seems then like you have solved your problem! Btw, if an argument is missed out etc an ArgumentError is not displayed to the user in the command line.